# Slow boot of (X)Ubuntu 19.10 on HP Laptop

Tags: boot, grub2, encryption, hp, boot-time

I recently bought a new HP Laptop (HP 830 G6) and installed Xubuntu 19.10 with full disk encryption (LUKS). I noticed slow startup times, but not from decryption of the disk, but more until I actually land at the decryption prompt. Between the first image here:

[image]

And the second image here, there are 5-10 seconds of waiting time:

[image]

I post this in Askubuntu, since the startup times are way faster in Windows 10 (yes, I realized that Windows hibernates most of the time and there is no disk encryption when booting Windows. But imho, it's not the enc-/decryption that's taking so long but something else. Once the passphrase for the decryption is entered, I am in the OS in <5 seconds).

Some information about the system:
Disk: Samsung 970 EVO Plus SSD (1000GB, M.2 2280)
RAM: 32 GB

And some commands that show the startup time:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 19.10
Release:    19.10
Codename:   eoan
```

Startup times:

```
$ systemd-analyze

Startup finished in 9.208s (firmware) + 6.187s (loader) + 49.805s (kernel) + 3.223s (userspace) = 1min 8.425s 
graphical.target reached after 3.218s in userspace


$ systemd-analyze critical-chain

graphical.target @3.218s
└─lightdm.service @1.109s +481ms
  └─systemd-user-sessions.service @1.085s +7ms
    └─network.target @1.068s
      └─NetworkManager.service @1.002s +63ms
        └─dbus.service @949ms
          └─basic.target @932ms
            └─sockets.target @931ms
              └─snapd.socket @923ms +7ms
                └─sysinit.target @910ms
                  └─systemd-timesyncd.service @716ms +191ms
                    └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service @701ms +10ms
                      └─local-fs.target @693ms
                        └─boot-efi.mount @684ms +8ms
                          └─boot.mount @677ms +5ms
                            └─systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-d58888fc\x288848\x2888e4\x288820\x2d5888889e42e8.service @644ms +31ms
                              └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-d58888fc\x288848\x2888e4\x288820\x2d5888889e42e8.device @643ms
```

Grub Bootloader:

```
$ cat /etc/default/grub

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=false
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

So far I disabled NetworkManager-wait, without a significant improvement:

```
$ sudo systemctl disable NetworkManager-wait-online.service
```

And I am kinda shocked by the 50 seconds of the kernel boot time...

Is there anything else I can try or do to speed up the startup times?